# Call a Web Service to get search result in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have implemented a tableView with a searchBar added to it. I want to call a service when user start typing the search keyword in the search bar. I know that I can call the service in the `change` event listener that will call the service.

I know that for every change in the search bar it is not good to call a service. So what is the efficient approach of using search bar when the search result is coming from a service call or what we can do to make the search efficient.

For example: the search functionality on Apple's App store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this for one of my test projects.  I would check in my change event that at least 3 characters were entered before I would attempt a look-up.  I have no idea why I went with 3, but it seemed like a decent number of characters for filtering my data.  I would also set a flag that a network request was in progress.  So if they entered 3 characters, you could kick off the search if no look-up was already in progress.  If there was a network request in progress, you could setup a wait interval to keep checking if the request came back and kick off an additional request when it is.  I would send back short lists of items, which for me was 25 so that my table appeared fast.

Though I didn't do this, you could track the interval of time between characters typed to make sure the user is finished typing.  For the best interval you will need to experiment with what is reasonable for an average user.  Get some feedback from typically non-power users on this.

I can see a potential issue where you are in the middle of a look-up, but the user is still typing.  You might need to track those character updates and perhaps kick off an additional search for the updated character string.  You might even check the character search string you sent at the time with the current characters in the input box and choose to abandon the list of look-up items you already received and just do another search.

You might want to show the list of items you did receive just so the user knows the app is working, but immediately send another request for look-up items automatically.  A user might eventually start hammering keys and think the app is unresponsive if you don't show something in the table once in a while.

Comment: This make sense and this is the only possible solution I see now.